# When is an item removed from its Item Pool?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac-rebirth

I want to do a **Jera** + **Blank Card** break.
I've found the *Blank Card* in a Basement shop but I hadn't enough coins to buy it, so I had to leave it there.

Anyway I've started generating several chests with *D20* + *Sharp Plug* and I've already [exhausted the Golden Chest item pool](http://bindingofisaacrebirth.gamepedia.com/Item_Pool), I'm finally getting Tresure Room items.

So I'm wondering: can I still find the *Blank Card* if I've already seen it (and not bought) in a shop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is: **YES**.
You can find an item you've only seen in the shop again. So, seeing (not buying!) an item does not remove it from the Item Pool.

I've just generated the *Blank Card* that I was looking for, here's the proof:

[image: Black card found!]

Comment: Alright, thanks for getting to the bottom of this.

Comment: @Jake You're welcome, there are so many things to discover in this game.